# How would a group with strong leadership skills create an initial government?

Tags: politics, government, underground, dystopia

A group of 1000 political “dissenters” and their families have been captured and forced into an underground bunker. Because many of them have some sort of background in politics and/or leadership, it is challenging to decide who will lead and how the government will be set up, but their survival depends on deciding and acting quickly.

How would they decide who leads and how they are chosen?

Comment: Have you done any research on your own? If so, what have you found?

Comment: @L.Dutch this is slightly new territory for me. I have not been overly interested in different government types until I realized I needed to create one. So I’ve done some basic research. Right now I feel like they want a democratic process leading to an oligarchy because they are coming from the repression of an authoritative theocracy. I’m reading a couple of psychology books and trying to find my old college leadership manuals. What I get stuck on is the competing voices of so many who are accustomed to being decision makers. How do they compromise to survive without losing their voices?

Comment: I'd say they should establish a meritocracy. Though what they should do and what they would do are entirely different things.

Comment: At what point in history is this occurring? It might be easy if it's modern and they have access to the internet and such.

Comment: I don't see the reason why 1000 people imprisoned in an underground jail would want to form a government. A government to govern what?

Comment: @Lemming even in today's jails, nobody is allowed access to the internet or cell phones. In prison work situations, some trusted prisoners are allowed limited internet access.

Comment: Is it 1000 people in total or 1000 dissenters? Also, do you need a fully functioning government or will you be satisfied with the power hierarchy system (the latter seems to be a more realistic possibility)? In addition to this, how pressing is the issue of survival? Is there any time for debates? Or do they need to start to look for food and water immediately?

Comment: @Lemming a meritocracy decimates sense. This is futuristic but they don’t have access to computers or the internet.

Comment: @Otkin it is 1000 that includes the dissenters and their families. So not all of them would be qualified as leaders, but a good portion of the adults would be.

Comment: @AlexP they are faced with living here permanently, or at least for the foreseeable future. They have children and elderly with them. While they may eventually seek to escape, for now survival is important and that means setting up systems for farming, waste management, etc. I would guess a group of educated people would recognize a need for leadership eventually.

Comment: Yes, I get all that. But leadership and government are different words, covering different realities. A group of a thousand people doesn't need and cannot support a government; what it needs is a boss. *One* boss. Consider the Ithaca of Ulysses; it had a small number of people, a few thousand. It had a king, Ulysses. That's it. No government. No need for one, or capacity to sustain one. Same for any really ancient city. Same for early Rome. Same for early medieval little kingdoms or stem duchies. Consider the Roman magistracies of the *cursus honorum*, and how they were added over centuries.

Comment: @Willough I don't see why you wouldn't want to have the guy who knows the most about farming be in charge of the crops. but alright, if you think it doesn't make sense then I'm not here to argue or change your mind

Comment: @Lemming It very much depends on the people involved. Imagine that the 'farmer' is a highly introverted woman not very interested in power struggles. At the same time, the group has 2-3 power-hungry men. If the group comes from a patriarchal society, there is a very high probability that one of those men will be in charge of farming instead of the woman. Moreover, there is a high probability that her advice will be dismissed.

Comment: I disagree that this question is too story-based. It is a question about a group dynamic. However, this question lacks information about the group to be answerable without too much speculation. We still need to know a bit more about the group's background (cultural, educational), group composition (age, gender), and the overall situation.

Answer (score 6):

The first thing I want to note here is that 1000 is a small enough number to allow for direct voting on a lot of issues.

The second important thing, already mentioned in some answers, is that they already have some leadership structures in place. If some of them know each other, they may be ready to delegate somebody to speak for them and represent their opinions. Depending on how developed this network is, you may already have your answer. If, say, there are five distinct groups with their leaders, the first thing that happens is that those leaders promise to work together for common good publicly. How effective that is, now that's a completely different question.

It is a third thing that makes this question very opinion-based/story-based. As you say, they are *political* dissenters. They, presumably, have strong views about politics and how it should be done. They will not just try to choose the most *rational* thing in the situation, they would want to enact their political *ideals*.

Are they the fans of the democracy? Do they even believe that one person should equal one vote? Or are they royalists, would they start to look for the closest heir of their royal line to lead them, even if symbolically? Do all of them share the same political ideal, or do they come from radically different groups? If the views are polarizing enough, they may first split into two groups, those groups choosing their leadership by whatever method, and then the corresponding leaders treating with each other.

Edit: in the continuation of the previous point, the important question is one of trust. What is their general culture, what is their background? Do they recognize they others in the same group as 'fellow sufferers', or would they hold grudges for whatever reasons?

For the goals of pure survival they do not need to *start* from organizing the government, actually. Some things can be done on grass-root initiative and recognition of merit. Say, your bunker has electrical systems that are quite complicated, and one of their number comes forward and says 'I'm an electrical engineer, I know how to do that and to fix it, I'll be by the generators, everyone who wants to help, come to me'. If his authority is recognized, you have that problem in hand without any government, there.

So, to summarize, a lot depends on what people are they, what is their culture, what are their beliefs, how well do they know each other or trust each other without knowing.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways they can form a government.

## Based on nationalism

When you have a lot of bored people with strong views on politics they are strongly motivated to escape. They could rally around whoever has the best escape plan skills, and work together to try and get a small number of people out to warn others of what is going on, and gather information from the guards.

## Based on promises

Someone may promise others favours inside or outside the prison. Whoever promises the most may be able to sway people to follow them.

## Based on charisma

A war hero or someone who is exceptionally charismatic may be able to unit the others behind their charisma.

## Based on favouritism from the guards

Some elite prisoners may unite with the guards, snitching on others to gain favors and special food, and use this to control the others.

Any or all of these may happen at once.

Answer (score 2):

**Through pre-established social dominance**

It's tagged as 'dystopia' and an underground bunker is being used so I'm taking some liberties here and assuming that the dissenters were in some way or form already in contact with each other before they were thrown into the situation that they find themselves in.

Whether by radio or by internet, these dissenters have already had a way to organize themselves in order to effectively politically dissent and as such would already have their own influencers and leaders among them. Best case scenario they keep on listening to those they've already been listening to, worst case scenario new leaders are chosen through some rather... assertive and violent actions by those with the capability to do so because they now view those who have been leading them as people who have failed to give them good or positive results while they were still relatively free(as is evidenced by them having been captured).

Answer (score 2):

**Elect a committee first**

With this population, you can't instate a dictatorial government. Everyone is a strong debater, everyone has opinions and personal goals. You'll get many dissidents, living in a community of dissidents.

At first glance, try democracy. You could define a few factions. The 1000 politicians will instate an elected committee of say, 10-20 chosen representatives, members of these factions. They could lay out a constitution. The committee would also prepare a military command structure, with people devising a plan to escape from the bunker.

The first committee will prepare the agenda for the Big Meeting.

You could have all 1000 inhabitants of the bunker attend that meeting and they will elect the first head of state, like a president, or another form of government.

**Constitutional monarchy could strengthen unity**

It depends on the state of cultural development.. but when the community would include some nobility, for instance family of a former monarch.. use that person as a unifying force, resulting in a constitutional monarchy.

Comment: Unfortunately, a group of dissidents will almost always disagree with each other, sometimes violently. The result is often that they don't form any government until a strong-willed person overthrows the committee and takes over. See Napoleon as an example. The committee spent so many years trying to get agreement that he was able to offer the promise of an actual government.